# sql : get consecutive group 'n' rows (could be inbetween)

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3, gaps-and-islands

Below is my theater table:

```
create table theater
(
   srno integer, 
   seatno integer, 
   available boolean
);

insert into theater
values
(1, 100,true),
(2, 200,true),
(3, 300,true),
(4, 400,false),
(5, 500,true),
(6, 600,true),
(7, 700,true),
(8, 800,true);
```

I want a sql which should take input as 'n' and returns me the first 'n' consecutive available seats, like

- if n = 2 output should be 100,200
- if n = 4 output should be 500,600,700,800

NOTE: I am trying to build an query for postgres 9.3

Comment: We may need more information to understand the question.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Are you really doing this using 3 different dbms products?!?

Comment: @wingedpanther the output 4nil want is consecutive, because of 400 is false, which mean it cannot be (100,200,300,400) so have to be (500,600,700,800) which all consecutive and true

Comment: Ohk .. got it guys !!

Comment: seems like a algorithm problem, maybe sql can do it, but for me I'd rather write a script and do it.

Comment: This is not trivial and **very much**  depending on the actual RDBMS. Please state your db vendor **and** version number!

Comment: I would like to add the "gaps-and-islands" tag, but there are allready 5 tags present. Which one should be removed?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

thanks guys, but i have done achieved it like below,

```
select srno, seatno from (
select *, count(0) over (order by grp) grp1 from (
  select t1.*,  
          sum(group_flag) over (order by srno) as grp
  from (
      select *,
             case
                when lag(available) over (order by srno) = available then null
                else 1
              end as group_flag
      from theater
  ) t1 ) tx ) tr where tr.available=true and tr.grp1 >= 2 limit 2
```

Comment: Strange comment, I think you should upvote answers If It helped for you. You answered to your own question and asking for upvotes...

Comment: lolz, please excuse me, i have asked to upvote only if it helped you too :)
please don't take it like i have had and answer for this question since long. if everyone insists, i may remove my comment to upvote it

Comment: I don't understand why this is being downvoted. It seems to return the correct result

Comment: I take that back, this will not work. It will also pick from the unavailable seats

Comment: @t-clausen.dk thanks that you first supported me, but i don't understand with what basis you are claiming that it will pick unavailable seats as well???
BTW, i would like to mention that the last sentence of my query 

<pre>) t1 ) tx ) tr where tr.grp1 >= 4 limit 4</pre>
here 4 is our 'n' and it does return the expected result, kindly request in case you agree, please don't downvote :(

Comment: Try finding the first 2 available seats with this data and your script(1, 100,1),
(4, 400,0),
(5, 400,0),
(6, 500,1),
(7, 600,1),
(8, 700,1),
(9, 800,1),
(10, 800,1)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk thanks a bunch dude for pointing out the mistake!! I have updated the answer accordingly, minor miss!!!

Comment: now you introduced a new error, your script does not return the correct result. I suggest you accept the script you found most useful

Answer (score 3):

In *SQL-Server* you can do It in following:

```
DECLARE @num INT = 4

;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT *,COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY cnt) pt  FROM
(
    SELECT tt.*
        ,(SELECT COUNT(srno) FROM theater t WHERE available <> 'true' and srno < tt.srno) AS cnt
    FROM  theater tt
    WHERE available = 'true'
) t1
)
SELECT TOP (SELECT @num) srno, seatno, available
FROM cte
WHERE pt >= @num
```

**OUTPUT**

```
srno    seatno  available
5       500 true
6       600 true
7       700 true
8       800 true
```

Comment: Seems to work now... upvote from my side and hope that the OP really needs SQL Server :-)

Comment: I'd advise you to remove the "#" as the OP will work against his physical table.

Answer (score 2):

This will find the available seats. written for sqlserver 2008+:

```
DECLARE @num INT = 4

;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT 
    srno-row_number() over (partition by available order by srno) grp, 
    srno, seatno, available
  FROM theater
), CTE2 as
(
  SELECT grp, count(*) over (partition by grp) cnt,
    srno, seatno, available 
  FROM CTE
    WHERE available = 'true'

)
SELECT top(@num)
  srno, seatno, available
FROM CTE2
WHERE cnt >= @num
ORDER BY srno
```

Result:

```
srno  seatno  available
5     500     1
6     600     1
7     700     1
8     800     1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        -- naive solution without window using functions
        -- [the funny +-100 constants are caused by
        -- "consecutive" seats being 100 apart]
        -- -------------------------------------------
WITH    bot AS ( -- start of an island --
        SELECT seatno FROM theater t
        WHERE  t.available
        AND NOT EXISTS (select * from theater x
                where x.available AND x.seatno = t.seatno -100)
        )
,       top AS ( -- end of an island --
        SELECT seatno FROM theater t
        WHERE t.available
        AND NOT EXISTS (select * from theater x
                where x.available AND x.seatno = t.seatno +100)
        )
,       mid AS ( -- [start,end] without intervening gaps --
        SELECT l.seatno AS bot, h.seatno AS top
        FROM bot l
        JOIN top h ON h.seatno >= l.seatno
                AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM theater x
                WHERE NOT x.available
                AND x.seatno >= l.seatno AND x.seatno <= h.seatno)
        )
        -- all the consecutive ranges
        -- [ the end query should select from this
        -- , using "cnt >= xxx" ]
SELECT bot, top
        , 1+(top-bot)/100 AS cnt
FROM mid;
```

---

Result:

```
 bot | top | cnt 
-----+-----+-----
 100 | 300 |   3
 500 | 800 |   4
(2 rows)
```